# TinyMCE Visual Editor Comment

Tags: wordpress, comments

I used "TinyMCE Visual Editor Comment" plugin in my theme. After click the "cancel reply" link in the reply comment form, the editor will not editable. I can not type any text in the editor. How can I fix this??

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the plugin. You should contact the plugin developer and ask him to resolve this.

Comment: Yes. You are right. This is plugin issue. Thank you. I used alternate method.